# Unicode big endian some character not getting properly from wchar_t array

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc

I am trying to extract the exact "unicode big endian" character from an array.

The values i directly taken from a file using big endian. i use vs 2015, mfc framework (unicode support).

> values: 亙亙亙Val

So these values directly taken from file to an array and without changing those values in the same array and directly printing to another txt file as unicode big endian format is possible. But changing some chars getting wrong result.

Directly written to editor.cpp file

```
wchar_t chr[] = {L'', L'亙', L'', L'', L'亙', L'亙', L'', L'', L'V', L'a', L'l', L'', L''};

wchar_t chVal = (wchar_t) chr[0]; // getting � or a rectangle mark 

if(chVal == L'')
  MessageBox(_T("Show msg")); // results wrong

wchar_t chVal = (wchar_t) chr[1]; // getting 亙 proper element.

if(chVal == L'亙')
  MessageBox(_T("Show msg")); // results correct
```

llly correct results in 'V', 'a', 'l'

=======================================

Before i placed the code

```
wchar_t* ch = _wsetlocale(LC_ALL, _T("Chinese"));
```

is it a problem from `_wsetLocale` ?

in the editor we can directly write those characters. But during debug or exe the results wrong.

why the editor not displaying some characters during debugging or execution.

================

## updated:

// wcstring is wchar_t array with unicode characters

CStringW str; wchar_t wh;

```
System::Text::Encoding^ encodingWr = System::Text::Encoding::BigEndianUnicode;
StreamWriter^ writer = gcnew StreamWriter("Converted.txt", true, encodingWr );
//String^ line = reader->ReadLine();

for(int ct = 0; ct< ctTot; ct++)
{

    int ln = wcstring[ct]; // correct number

    wh = /*(wchar_t)*/ wcstring[ct]; //wrong

    str.Format(_T("UNNUM %d %lc"), ln, wh);

        /* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/how-to-convert-between-various-string-types?view=vs-2017*/
        // Convert a wide character CStringW to a
        // System::String.
        String ^systemstringw = gcnew String(str);
        //systemstringw += " (System::String)";
        //Console::WriteLine("{0}", systemstringw);
        //delete systemstringw;

    writer->WriteLine(systemstringw);
        delete systemstringw;

    OutputDebugString(str);

}
```

but needed to print on file correct unicode character. 
so compiler problems need to know too.

Comment: `wchar_t chVal = (wchar_t) chr[0];` - this cast _should_ be unnecessary; `char[0]` appears to be a `wchar_t` already. The presence of this cast points at deeper problems, beyond the code we see here.

Comment: Not sure if related, but I'd recommend that you always write a source file in plain ASCII. It might be that your compiler has problems understanding the source file. If you need to instantiate non-ASCII characters in code, use their UTF8 number code, like `std::wstring str = L"\u20AC";` instead of typing the euro symbol €. In the long run, you might instead want to create a file with the symbols and read that file to obtain your array. As the file is specifically read as UTF8 (or whatever), there should not be any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Character and utf  U+20007

Comment: Please see the update in my post. It express the char is not getting but getting the unicode value. And the point is i have to print the proper unicode character after verifying (if ;;; else statement)

Comment: Windows and .NET use UTF-16LE strings. Windows compilers store UTF-16 string literals in little endian. Most Unicode-based APIs on Windows only know little endian. So, if the input file is encoded in big endian instead, and your file I/O doesn't convert to little endian when populating the array, then you will have to manually swap every alternating *byte* (not *character*) in the array before then manipulating it using little endian values, and then swap the bytes again when writing the array back to file as big endian.

Comment: Thanks, already got answer. [Exact answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f10e2a54-d5e0-431d-a916-80d862430402/some-unicode-characters-big-endian-not-getting-properly-on-debugexe-run-times-but-we-can-write?forum=vcgeneral)